How to write complex Snowflake SQL queries in Excel
I have installed ODBC driver for Snowflake on my Windows machine. I have also connected to Snowflake in Excel using the ODBC driver :

Now I want to write complex Snowflake SQL queries in Excel and generate results in Excel and save the Excel file and refresh the Excel file when there is new data loaded from the source Snowflake tables. Is there a way where I can copy paste the Snowflake SQL query into Excel, execute the query in Excel and generate the result?
Here is an example of a Snowflake SQL query:
select
    trim(RES) RES, trim(RES1)  RES1, trim(RES2)  RES2
from
    TEST123
where
    trim(RES) in ('TRER');


In Excel you can navigate to  Data | Get Data | From Other Sources | From ODBC to retrieve data from any database (including Snowflake) using ODBC


thanks it works now. Just one question not related to my question. Can we automatically refresh this excel or schedule this excel to be refreshed ? Because if i have 100 excel files with 100 different sql queries then i have to open every excel and click on refresh manually for all this 100 reports.

There are various ways to automate Excel depending on what tools you are familiar with (.Net, Python, Java). For Python, you may want to look at https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/

thanks but if we dont want to use any programming  language and rather needs to refresh in excel only then is it not possible ?
